# Get ClassCastException when using multiple services from spring boot restcontroller

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot

My spring boot application have behaved pretty well until I needed to access two services from the controller. In the method CreateCompany I want to check that the user exists before I store the company in the db. The company data is received properly, as is the adminId path variable.

This works once, but if I want to insert another company for the same user, I get a ClassCastException for when I try to look up the user.

A weird thing though, is that I in a different class is using the CompanyTagService to successfully insert tags into a database. When debugging, it appears as a CompanyTagService object, while the CompanyService and UserService are proxies. This is suspicious to me, but I know to little about spring proxies to figure out anything useful from it.

What am I doing wrong?

CompanyServiceBean.java

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping( value="/api/company")
public class CompanyController {

    @Value( "${application.config.logo_folder}" )
    private String logoFolder;

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Autowired
    private CompanyService service;

    @Autowired
    private CompanyTagService tagService;

    @Autowired
    private UserService uService;

    @RequestMapping( 
            value="/admin/{adminId}",
            method=RequestMethod.POST, 
            consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, 
            produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE )
    public ResponseEntity< ? > CreateCompany( @RequestBody Company company, @PathVariable( "adminId") Long adminId ){
        Company ret = null;
        ResponseEntity< ? > resp = null;
        User u = uService.findOne( adminId ); //This is where the exception occurrs.

        if( null != u )
            logger.info( "User {} was found.", u.getFirstName() );

        logger.info( "Creating company record for admin with id {}", adminId);

        if( u == null ){
            resp = new ResponseEntity< RestResult >( new RestResult( "The user id must be set", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST ), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST );
        }
        else {
            company.setAdminId(adminId);
            try{
                ret = service.create( company );
                resp = new ResponseEntity< Company >( ret, HttpStatus.CREATED );
            }
            catch( DataIntegrityViolationException ie ){
                resp = new ResponseEntity< RestResult >( new RestResult( "Company name or org. no. was already in use", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST ), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
            }
            catch( Exception e ){
                resp = new ResponseEntity< RestResult >( new RestResult( "Could not create the company.", HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR ), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
            }
        }

        return( resp );
    }
... Other service methods
```

UserServiceBean.java:

```
@Service
@Transactional( propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS, readOnly = true )
public class UserServiceBean implements UserService {

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepo;

    @Override
    @CachePut( value="EntWeb", key="#result.id" )
    @Transactional( propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = false )
    public User create(User user) {
        User ret = null;

        if( user.getId() == null ) {
            ret = userRepo.save( user );
        }

        return( ret );
    }

    @Override
    @Cacheable( value="EntWeb", key="#id")
    public User findOne(Long id) {
        User ret = userRepo.findOne( id );

        return( ret );
    }

... Other Service methods
```

The error output

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.entweb.model.Company cannot be cast to org.entweb.model.User
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy126.findOne(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at org.entweb.web.api.CompanyController.CreateCompany(CompanyController.java:58) ~[classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:817) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:731) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
```

Comment: Can you remove cache to confirm that it is not causing the problem? It can be that you have common cache space, and that is why it fails. Hope it is the problem, because I have no other ideas.

Comment: That seems to have been the answer! I Tried to remove the transactions before, but that didn't change anything!

Comment: Then the question arise; How do I implement Caching in a situation like this? Any suggestions?

Comment: BTW,  `key="#id"` is useless, that's what the cache abstraction does by default for you (computing a key based on the method parameter(s))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only problem comes to (my) mind is cache. Namely - putting different objects into one cache. Peter confirmed that it is the problem.

To fix that... There are two ways:

- one is to have global id, and that will make all cache calls valid, with no collisions.
- other way is to have different cashes. Pros:

  - you don't need to change existing code,
  - you have control on caching each class.

To have it done, look at [cachePut](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/annotation/CachePut.html) spec. Values property is the one you are using to tell which caches should be updated, and contain this particular result object. Most projects uses dot prefixes - `EntWeb.users.admins` - or maybe `entweb.users` is enough. Beauty is that you can later change it.

Comment: Yes, when you think about it is quite logic that caching different object-types with the same key will yield some confusion ;) I solved this with separate caches like this:     GuavaCacheManager cacheManager = new GuavaCacheManager( "EntWeb", "EntWebUser" );      I will try to create the caches using the appliation.properties instead though.